# Regex to remove all of a single type of character

Tags: regex

I would like to remove all single quote chars from a line that starts *CREATE*

e.g. change

```
CREATE TABLE 'Item_Value' (     'itemID'    Integer not NULL,   'value' Integer,    'currencyType'  TEXT,   PRIMARY KEY(itemID) );
INSERT INTO  Item_Value  (itemID,value,currencyType) VALUES (2,55,'CREDITS'),
 (20,60,'CREDITS'),
 (22,310,'CREDITS'),
 (23,310,'CREDITS'),
 (24,75,'CREDITS'),
```

into

```
CREATE TABLE Item_Value ( itemID Integer not NULL, value Integer,   currencyType TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(itemID) );
INSERT INTO Item_Value (itemID,value,currencyType) VALUES (2,55,'CREDITS'),
 (20,60,'CREDITS'),
 (22,310,'CREDITS'),
 (23,310,'CREDITS'),
 (24,75,'CREDITS'),
```

I have tried (using notepad++)

Find: ^(CREATE.*)\'
Replace \1
But I can't even manage to find the first one, let alone replace them all

I have also noticed there are strings on the data loading lines that have such things as `''I'' key` and `End of the sentence. ')`

Comment: Does the answer have to work in notepad++ or can we use anything we want?

Comment: I would like it to work in notepad++, but I can work with any answer

Comment: Well, in vim I'd simply use `:g/^CREATE/s/'//g`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex in Notepad++:

```
Find: (?:^CREATE|\G)[^'\n]*\K'
Replace:
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fA4wG7/2)

Answer (score 0):

If the spaces are surrounding the quotes are also in your original file use this regex:

`(?<=\s)'|'(?=\s)`
Replace with empty string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gT5dE3/1).

Comment: That doesn't check for `CREATE`, though.

Comment: correct. There are instances in the data strings that should not be changed. I'll add them to the question